# Как реализовать часы работы

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

Как реализовать хранение времени работы заведения в бд (структура)

Хочу реализовать что-то подобное

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интересует вопрос хранения этих данных в БД

Как их правильно расположить, при этом, чтобы можно было реализовать поиск по времени

Comment: Как периоды. От-До. Скажем, в формате DayOfWeek*24+Hour. Соответственно поиск (если не нужно искать периоды с переходом через границу недели) превращается в вульгарный BETWEEN. Нужно ли дробить непрерывный дневной период на часовые (или с иной дискретностью) - решай сам, зависит от задач (но мне необходимость такого кажется маловероятной).

Comment: @Akina можно не много разжевать, то есть в 1 столбце хранить все время в формате  DayOfWeek*24+Hour через запятую? Или делать отдельные 7 столбцов(Пн-Вс). Нужно скорей От и До, без обедов и будет скорей не поиск, а показывать на данный момент Открыто/Закрыто

Comment: Отдельная таблица. В ней одна запись - один интервал. Т.е. для показанных исходных в ней будет 6 записей (первый скрин). А потом это уже разворачивается в план-график на втором скрине - на основании даты и времени ставится либо не ставится галка в соответствии с данными из таблицы рабочих периодов.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Может и ошибаюсь, но как по мне можно хранить просто так

```
week_day | time_start | time_end
```

`week_day` можно хранить в формате числа 0=Воскресенье, 1=Понедельник и т.д. или в каком угодном порядке, потом можно сделать [Accessor](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-mutators#accessors-and-mutators) который возвращает по индексу человекопонятное имя.

`time_start` и `time_end` в формате как на первом скриншоте(09:30, 22:05 и т.д.)

---

#### Примеры фильтров:

Если диапазон находиться в диапазне между $start и $end

```
$users = Model::where([
    ['time_start', '>=', $start],
    ['time_end', '<=', $end]
])->get();
```

Если текущее время находиться в диапазоне

```
$now = now()->format('H:i'); // Приводит к формату 11:45

$users = \App\User::where([
    ['time_start', '<=', $now],
    ['time_end', '>=', $now]
])->get();
```

---

Если нужна привязаность к временной зоне, то надо хранить в UTC, при сохранении переводить с таймзоны пользователя в UTC и при выводе выводить по таймзоне пользователя.

Если в конфиге timezone UTC, то вот примеры:

Сохранение в UTC:

```
$userTZ = 'Europe/Kiev';
$timeStr = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', '13:20')
$result = \Carbon\Carbon::parse($timeStr, $userTZ)->tz('UTC')->format('H:i')
```

Вывод по таймзоне пользователя:

```
$result = \Carbon\Carbon::createFromFormat('H:i', '13:20')->tz($userTZ)->format('H:i')
```